# Intermittent Modernizr/jQuery plugin error "Object [object Object] has no method..."

Tags: jquery, datatables, modernizr

I use [Modernizr to load](http://modernizr.com/docs/#load) the [DataTables jQuery plugin](http://datatables.net/); once the plugin has been loaded, I use Modernizr's complete method to execute the DataTables function against all tables classed as tablesorter:

```
<script>
Modernizr.load([
{
    load: [
        '//path/to/jquery.dataTables.min.js'
    ],
    complete: function() {
        //power table sorting
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('table.tablesorter').each( function() {
                if ($(this).find('tbody').prop('rows').length > 2) {
                    $(this).dataTable({
                        "aaSorting": [ ],
                        "bAutoWidth": false,
                        "bFilter": 0,
                        "bLengthChange": false,
                        "bPaginate": 0,
                        "iDisplayLength": 50,
                        "sDom": "t"
                    });
                };
            });
        });
    }
}
]);
</script>
```

Most of the time, this code behaves as intended. **From time to time--perhaps 10%--this code will error**:

> Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'dataTable'

Do I misunderstand the complete method of Modernizr? Does it run after the file has been downloaded, but not necessarily after the code has been parsed/executed?

A couple of notes:

- Not every page in this application uses DataTables, so
- the erroring script is called from the document `body`
- but jQuery is loaded, also by Modernizr, from the document's `head`:

  Modernizr.load([
  {
      both: [
          '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js',
          '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.0/jquery-ui.min.js',
          '//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js'
      ]
  }
  ]);

Comment: I wonder if datatables is loading before jquery is included in the page.

Comment: If jQuery weren't loaded, wouldn't it error at `$(document).ready()`?

Comment: theoretically yes, but might be worth testing. First you need to get to the point where you can reliably re-create the issue. The fact in this case is that *"10% of the time"* the datatable plugin isn't installed on the jquery instance you are using. Typically if it's something that only happens sometimes, it's going to be a race condition, likely related to the way you are asynchronously loading jquery and it's plugins.